# What does dag.cli() exactly do?

Tags: airflow

The [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.cli) simply mentions the following

> Exposes a CLI specific to this DAG

and is not very informative. It would be great if someone could explain (preferably with the help of an example) what it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what `dag.cli()` does, I created a sample DAG as follows ([source](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html)): -

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from textwrap import dedent

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG

# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    # These args will get passed on to each operator
    # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
    default_args={
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
        # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
        # 'pool': 'backfill',
        # 'priority_weight': 10,
        # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
        # 'wait_for_downstream': False,
        # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
        # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300),
        # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
        # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
        # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
        # 'sla_miss_callback': yet_another_function,
        # 'trigger_rule': 'all_success'
    },
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:
    dag.cli()
    # t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date',
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='sleep',
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command='sleep 5',
        retries=3,
    )
    t1.doc_md = dedent(
        """\
    #### Task Documentation
    You can document your task using the attributes `doc_md` (markdown),
    `doc` (plain text), `doc_rst`, `doc_json`, `doc_yaml` which gets
    rendered in the UI's Task Instance Details page.
    ![img](http://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Semesters/2012-01/491/import%20soul.png)

    """
    )

    dag.doc_md = __doc__  # providing that you have a docstring at the beginning of the DAG
    dag.doc_md = """
    This is a documentation placed anywhere
    """  # otherwise, type it like this
    templated_command = dedent(
        """
    {% for i in range(5) %}
        echo "{{ ds }}"
        echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
    {% endfor %}
    """
    )

    t3 = BashOperator(
        task_id='templated',
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command=templated_command,
    )

    t1 >> [t2, t3]
```

Running `python ~/airflow/dags/tutorial.py` gave me the following output: -

```
$ python ~/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
usage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...

    positional arguments:
      GROUP_OR_COMMAND
    
        Groups:
          dags          Manage DAGs
          tasks         Manage tasks
    
        Commands:
    
    optional arguments:
      -h, --help        show this help message and exit
    
    airflow command error: the following arguments are required: GROUP_OR_COMMAND, see help above.
```

If I comment the line `dag.cli()` (first line in the context manager for DAG), running `python ~/airflow/dags/tutorial.py` doesn't output anything.